# Using principal component analysis to reduce dimension, how can we know the distance between data points is reduced and features are uncorrelated?

Tags: linear-algebra, principal-component-analysis

Using PCA, if we reduce the dimension of a dataset $x_1, \dots, x_n \in \mathbb{R}^d$ of
mean zero, then we can get a dimensionally reduced dataset $y_1, \dots , y_n \in \mathbb{R}^k$, for some $1\leq k \leq d$

How can we know that PCA shrinks the dataset between data points?
And how can we know that new features are uncorrelated?

My idea: 
To show the distance: we can show that $\|y_i - y_j\| \leq \|x_i - x_j\|$
And for $f^{(i)} = (y_{1,i}, y_{2,i}, \dots , y_{n,i}) \in \mathbb{R}^n$ where $ 1 \in \{1,\dots,k\}$ we want to show that for all $i \neq j, f^{(i)} \perp f^{(j)}$

We know that
$y_i = \langle x_i,e_j \rangle$ 
$\|y_i - y_j\| =\sqrt{\sum_{i=1}^n(y_i-y_j)^2}$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The $n \times k$ matrix  $Y$ (whose rows are $y_1, \ldots, y_n$) is $Y = XV_{1:k}$ where the columns of $V_{1:k} \in \mathbb{R}^{d \times k}$ are the orthonormal eigenvectors of $X^\top X$ corresponding to the largest $k$ eigenvalues.

- Note that $Y^\top Y = V_{1:k}^\top X^\top X V_{1:k}$. The left-hand side is a matrix whose $(i,j)$ entry is $\langle f^{(i)}, f^{(j)}\rangle$. The right-hand side is a $k \times k$ diagonal matrix whose diagonal entries are the largest $k$ eigenvalues of $X^\top X$. Since the matrix is diagonal, we have $f^{(i)} \perp f^{(j)}$ for $i \ne j$.
- $y_i = x_i^\top V_{1:k}$, so $$\|y_i - y_j\|^2 = \|(x_i - x_j)^\top V_{1:k}\|^2 = (x_i - x_j)^\top V_{1:k} V_{1:k}^\top (x_i - x_j)
  = \sum_{m=1}^k (x_{i,m} - x_{j,m})^2
  \le \sum_{m=1}^d (x_{i,m} - x_{j,m})^2
  = \|x_i - x_j\|^2.$$
  (Above, we noted that $V_{1:k} V_{1:k}^\top$ is a $d \times d$ diagonal matrix with $k$ ones and $d-k$ zeros on the diagonal.)